# spring input path for list

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring input path in jsp

ex:

```
<div class="cell label"> 
    <form:label path="order.paymentTransactions.payerEmail">Payer Mail</form:label>
</div> 
<div class="cell"> 
    <form:input path="order.paymentTransactions.payerEmail" name="payerEmail"/>
</div>
```

here, order is my main object and inside order, paymentTransaction is a List, i have to input data to check through dao in payerEmail.

But it showing error to me and invalid path. Please suggest me a good way to define the input path in jsp. thanks

Comment: You should include the exact error in your question. Makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: order.paymentTransactions.payerEmail invalid path

Comment: Order is my dataObject, inside order i have List<PaymentTransaction>, payerEmail is a variable declared inside paymentTransaction. I need to to pass input data to payerEmail. Please help me how to define the path. thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While mapping a list of bean in Spring, it is difficult to provide path attribute. You can replace the `<form:input>` with plain html `<input>`.

```
<input name="order.paymentTransactions[0].payerEmail" />
```

Here's a complete example to map List as form object in Spring MVC

Example: [Spring MVC: Multiple Row Form Submit using List of Beans](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/)

The above example also discuss why it is difficult to use `<form:input>` while working with Lists. Its because if you try to use something like below:

```
<form:input path="order.paymentTransactions[0].payerEmail" name="payerEmail"/>
```

Spring will simple render this as HTML:

```
<input name="order.paymentTransactions0.payerEmail" />
```

Ignoring the brackets [  ].

Thus its impossible to use `<form:input>` for mapping List.

Comment: thanks..i got the answer, because i am displaying all info as list, for my case:${orderList.order.paymentTransactions[0].payerEmail} it working fine.

Comment: @HungTran Which version of Spring you used?

Comment: @Viral Patel: I used Spring 3.1.0.Release. Spring only stripped off the bracked from id attribute, and still kept the bracket of name attribute.

<input id="employees0.name" name="employees[0].name" type="text" value="">

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks @Viral Patel

Comment: I don't think this works if we want to see list of payerEmail. I tried it and as you can see in the code only first email appears. How can I display all the list. I tried using status index as shown in other answer and that does not work either.

Answer (score 4):

We can do mapping of list through spring . Please update in your site. Thank you.

Example:

```
<c:forEach var="marksList" items="${personDTO.marksList}" varStatus="status">

<form:input path="marksList[${status.index}].hindi" />
```

Comment: I'm glad I try out this answer even though it had a negative vote. Yes this answer worked for me. here you go a up vote!

Answer (score 0):

You can do these:

```html
<c:set var="list" value="order.paymentTransactions[0].payerEmail" scope="page" />

<form:input path="${list}" name="payerEmail"/>
```

These worked for me.