# assign form field value to a variable in list spring

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have form which has object in it. that object has a list of object (which has variables on form view) so something like this:

```
FormClass{
  Obj1 oj1; //getter-setter method included
}

class Obj1{
  List<Obj2> obj2; //getter-setter for this included
}

class Obj2{
  String title;
  String name;
  //getter-setter included for all fields
}
```

Now I want to assign textbox (on form) value to field in Obj2 (say to title).

I tried using obj1.obj2[0].title however this does not work.

Could you please comment.

Comment: please format your code by selecting the code and pressing ctrl+k

Comment: got the answer at :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838021/spring-input-path-for-list