# Jquery validate not working for VO inside the form

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-validate

I have a model and inside model i have a vo.

```
Class Model{
    private VO vo1;

    getVO1{
    }
    setVO1{
    }
}


Class VO{
    private String name;

    getName{
    }
    setName{
    }
}
```

In JSP

```
<form:input path="vo1.name" name="name" id="name">
```

In JS, if i try to validate the form , errors are not throwing.

```
$("form1").validate({
    rules : {
        "name": required
    },
    messages : {
        "name" : {
            required : "name mandatory
    }
});
```

the same JS code ll work for below code

```
Class Model{
    private String name;

    getName{
    }
    setName{
    }
}


<form:input path="name" name="name" id="name">
```

Need to know why it is not validating the field inside the VO of the model. Does the spec is like this ? Kindly help

Comment: Show the rendered HTML for both cases.  It's JavaScript, the rendered HTML is all that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, you need to look at (and show us) the ***rendered*** HTML for each case to clearly see what's going wrong.  JavaScript does not care about how you construct your model or really anything else in your server-side code.  JavaScript runs in the browser and only sees how the HTML/DOM was constructed.

Your first case...

```
<form:input path="vo1.name" name="name" id="name">
```

would be rendered as...

```
<input name="vo1.name" id="name" type="text">
```

As per the Spring MVC documentation for `input` tags, there is no option called `name`.  Instead, `path` is rendered in the browser as the HTML `name` attribute.

Since your rendered HTML `name` is `vo1.name`, then that's what you need to use within the `.validate()` method for declaring your rules...

```
$("#form1").validate({ // <- '#' was missing from selector
    rules: {
        "vo1.name": "required" // <- boolean rule declaration needs quotes
    },
    messages: {
        "vo1.name": {
            required: "name mandatory"  // <- closing quotation mark was missing
        }  // <- closing brace was missing
    } 
});
```

Pay attention to your JavaScript console errors.  You were missing a closing quote on the custom message as well as a closing brace.  Also, the shorthand for the `required` rule must be enclosed in quotes or else it's interpreted as a variable name.  And finally, you were missing the `#` in front of `form1` within the jQuery selector.  All of these will break the jQuery or JavaScript and most give console errors.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ge2xgt8n/**

**References**:

1. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841548/594235